# Special characters like '&' and '£' cuts my the twitter text that get passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I seems that everytime `@item.title` contains any special characters like '&' or '£' etc it cutz the twitter text that get passed.

Is there any good solutions to fix this? Any kind of help is very useful for me

here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var loc = $(this).attr('href');
  window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + "@item.Title. "  + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
  });
```

This is how it looks like try click on it:

> "http://twitter.com/share?url=undefined&text=A&E threat to Royal Glamorgan

item.title have following text:

```
A&E threat to Royal Glamorgan
```

"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using encodeURIComponent helps:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: How would tha look? I tried: window.open(encodeURI('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + "@item.Title. News via www.newsifi.com"  + '&', 'twitterwindow'), 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0'); but its not working the window.open is not even working anymore

Answer (score 0):

put this around all your razor parameters

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Title));
```

using `encodeURIComponent()` like Lilith2k3 answered will work , but don't encode the `&` and `=` that are part of the url , just encode the parameters

Comment: JSON encoding is the absolute wrong thing to use in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the one

```
window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + @item.Title + '. News via www.newsifi.com' + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 225) + ', left=' + $(window).width() / 2 + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
```